# How do I prevent page jump scroll when inserting iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

When I insert an iframe w/jquery, it jumps the scroll of the page down to where the iframe is. How do I prevent this? Why does it happen?

```
var code = '<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>';
$('#target').html(code);
```

This also illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/andys627/VPJvM/

Comment: i tested on FF and IE, and it does not, there is a vertical scroll but the page is still positioned at the top

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save last scroll position, add iframe then scroll back to your saved position. Here's how

```
var lasttop = $(window).scrollTop();
var code = '<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>';
$('#target').html(code);
$(window).scrollTop(lasttop );
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your `src="#"` attribute as it's an empty hash the browser scrolls when you have no hash-tag in your url